# Repeating value on a cell based on the number of times on another cell but starts at a column defined by another cell

Tags: google-sheets

I am building a personal sinking fund spreadsheet where an amount is split into equal parts depending on the number of months you specify. I used the 'SLIT()' and 'REPT()' to do this but I wanted the REPT() to start based on the starting month I specify.

[image]

`Start Month = February No of repetitions = 5 'REPT()' should start from column labelled FEB and NOT JAN...`

I am not sure if this can be done. Hope someone can help. Thanks!

Formula Used from first row under JAN in the image.
`IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REPT(H2&",", G2), ",")),"")`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include a text-based example or, preferably, share an *editable* example sheet. Please be sure to define your input: What are they? How are they formatted? How are they derived? (Manually entered/copy-pasted? Derived from another program?) **and** define your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=LET(
  joined, 
  JOIN(
    "|", 
    VSTACK(
      MAP(SEQUENCE(A1), LAMBDA(i, "")), 
      MAP(SEQUENCE(B1), LAMBDA(i, C1))
    )
  ), 
  SPLIT(RIGHT(joined, LEN(joined)-1), "|", true, false)
)
```

- `A1` - the number of months you want to start with (offset).
- `B1` - the number of months to apply to after the offset.
- `C1` - the value to repeat.

Comment: Thank you for your response and suggestion. I was getting a "Wrong number of arguments to LET. Expected an odd number, but got 2 arguments." error.

Comment: @DaddySNP Strange. I have just tried the formula and it worked.  This is a spreadsheet with an example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1URnfpSQ1tZqOHqOsmolFekguklVE_dhDYBZ9HUHUOtQ/edit#gid=0

Comment: just had the time to check this back and I was able to correct the error using your example. I had an extra () B1 SEQUENCE that was causing the error. Thanks! BTW, I doing a SUM() for each month column but is returning '0' instead of the sum. Still figuring out this one.

Comment: @DaddySNP Hm.. I have added per-month `SUM` to the [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1URnfpSQ1tZqOHqOsmolFekguklVE_dhDYBZ9HUHUOtQ/edit#gid=0).  Seems to work fine.  Can you share the values in a month column?

Comment: values under the month columns are all currency (set in format). A1 is derived from MONTH() of starting month, B1 is calculated using the DATEDIF() in months (number of months from start to end of repeats), C1 is total amount (currency) divided by B1. Now, I copied your sample and converted the cells under the month columns to currency and I was able to see the non-summation too...

Comment: I changed the cell formats under the month column names as well as the C1 cell to "number" and this fixed the problem. I kept the month sum and the total sum in currency format though. Not sure why I cannot do a sum though originally. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @DaddySNP Glad to hear that it all worked out.  If the formula solved your issue, could you mark the question as answered, please.